# debug in browser using testacular (now karma)

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

I am trying to figure out the best way to debug my unit tests when I break them. Typically in previous test environments I could just run the tests in the browser and breakpoint the test, or the code and see why my test was failing. I can't seem to figure out how to do that with testacular. Is there an easy way to debug unit tests?

Comment: Hah! I'm not surprised they changed the name.

Comment: I think the name 'karma' is too generic and applied to too many different ideas... they should go back to testacular imo :)

Comment: Quite an astonishingly long conversation here https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/376

Conclusion: the diversity of human life, opinion and behaviour is reflected in the community of coders.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MVw8N3hTfCI

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Include "browsers = ['Chrome'];" in your karma.config file.

When Chrome opens, you should see "Karma - connected" at the top, with a "Debug" button to the upper-right.

Click this debug button, and a "Karma DEBUG RUNNER" tab will open.  Then, simply right-click, inspect element, and debug as you normally would.

Comment: @Lucas why not?  This is THE way Karma intended you to debug tests in the browser.  The accepted answer works, but this is a more straight-forward and flexible alternative that's baked right into the runner.  Am I missing the point of the question?

Comment: This seems to be the best solution to me.  If you run the tests using this link you will see failures in the debugging tool console window and you can reload as needed to run them again.

Answer (score 67):

1. In `karma.conf.js`:

   ```
   browsers = ['Chrome'];
   ```
2. In your failing spec:

   ```
   it('spec', function() {
       debugger; // This is like setting a breakpoint
       // ...
   });
   ```
3. Run Karma.
4. Go to the newly opened Chrome Browser, open the console and refresh the page.

Now in Chrome's Developer Tools source tab you should see the execution stopped at the debugger.

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for... A way to breakpoint so I can see context.

Comment: Also realized that you can just set karma to

    singleRun: false

and then just go to the browser that opens and breakpoint there in the tests, or the code :D

Comment: A link to the relevant documentation would really improve the answer. Thanks.

Comment: The only Karma specific thing is step 1, which is documented here: karma-runner.github.io/0.10/config/configuration-file.html. 
The rest is generic javascript debugging, I didn't find it on the docs at the time.

Comment: I was running into this issue again once updating to 0.10.   I want to point out in karma.config.js setting 'singleRun: false' will do the trick - if you're also using grunt - (with yeoman) the rules set in the Gruntfile.js will override the karma.config.js so change or remove the settings for karma there as well. Cheers!

Comment: This "works", but Karma has a addressed this with a "Debug" button that appears on the test page.  Given that feature, it's unnecessary to add "debugger;" to your code whenever you want to debug tests.  Just click the button and debug like you normally would.

Comment: I don't understand what happends when I click the "Debug" button. It opens another tab with this url: "http://localhost:9876/debug.html", but nothing shows. How could I proceed?

Comment: @canotto90 in that newly-opened tab, you can debug like you normally would.  For instance, in Chrome or Firefox, you'd right-click, inspect element.

Answer (score 9):

I found the following way to debug which doesn't require to make any changes in code (like adding "debugger" statement)

Set the "singleRun" as false in karma config file, such that karma will be listening on debug port and you can run the test again in browser launching the URL given below and debug:

> Go to the captured browser and click the "DEBUG" button (or open
>   `http://localhost:9876/debug.html`) and use the web inspector to see
>   what's going on. (You may need to refresh the debug.html page for it
>   to kick in once the web inspector is open.)

Answer (score 0):

In your console you should notified which it() statement is breaking, and why. For example:

```
Todos Add a new todo should add a new todo FAILED
expected todo.length to be 1 but was 0
```

However, you may find it useful to set

```
logLevel = LOG_DEBUG;
```

in your karma.conf.js file.

Comment: this still doesn't get me what I'm looking for. For example an error like:
'TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined' is a little ambiguous to know what needs to be fixed.

I'm looking for a way to run karma in chrome, with chromes breakpoints so that I can see context to whats going on.