# Generating html spec runner using karma

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I'm considering moving from grunt-contrib-jasmine to karma to run my jasmine tests. One thing I can't see how to replicate in karma is saving a html spec runner which I can then manually open in the browser (easy to do in grunt by using `keepRunner: true`). Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Turns out tis question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906903/debug-in-browser-using-testacular-now-karma