# AngularJS, spies, and resolving promises

Tags: angularjs, jasmine

I am writing tests for a controller.  One method calls a method in a service, which utilises a promise.  In my test, I have mocked the service, and (I think) correctly mocked the promise.  I have been following this blog entry: http://codingsmackdown.tv/blog/2012/12/28/mocking-promises-in-unit-tests/.

Here is the test code:

```
describe('Controller: ResultsController', function () {
    'use strict';
    var ctrl;
    var ResultsServiceMock;
    var RouteServiceMock;
    var $scope;
    var mockResults;
    var mockPromise;
    var q;
    var deferred;

    beforeEach(module('waApp'));

    beforeEach(function() {
        ResultsServiceMock = {
            get: function(query) {
                deferred = q.defer();
                return deferred.promise;
            }
        };
        RouteServiceMock = {
            getParams: function() {
            }
        };
    });

    beforeEach(inject(function(
        $rootScope,
        $controller,
        $q
    ) {
        $scope =  $rootScope.$new();
        q = $q;
        ctrl = $controller('ResultsController', {
            $scope: $scope,
            results: ResultsServiceMock,
            route: RouteServiceMock
        });
    }));

    it('Should simulate requesting results from the api', function() {
        spyOn(ResultsServiceMock, 'get').andCallThrough();
        spyOn(RouteServiceMock, 'getParams').andReturn({input:'hamburger'});
        $scope.getResults({input:'hamburger'});  // TODO give params.  try query()
        deferred.resolve();
        $scope.$root.$digest();
        expect($scope.getResults).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
});
```

However, when I run the tests, I get the following error:

```
Chrome 35.0 (Mac) Controller: ResultsController Should simulate requesting results from the api FAILED

TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/maryc/wa/app/results/results-controller_test.js:70:17)

Chrome 35.0 (Mac): Executed 14 of 14 (1 FAILED) (0.313 secs / 0.093 secs)
```

I don't understand where this error is coming from; is it because the spy call on ResultsServiceMock is not working?  Any help would be appreciated.

The function getResults is as follows:

```
 $scope.getResults = function(params) {¬
     $scope.$emit('startGetResults');¬
     $scope.loading = true;¬
     $scope.podRequestStatus.init = false;¬
     $scope.podRequestStatus = {¬
         async: {}¬
     };¬

     var didyoumeans;¬
     if(params.didyoumeans) {¬
         didyoumeans = params.didyoumeans;¬
         delete params.didyoumeans;¬
     }¬

     ResultsService.get(params).success(function(result) {¬
         $scope.$emit('getResultsSuccess');¬
         if(!_.isUndefined(didyoumeans)) {¬
             $scope.results.queryresult.didyoumeans = didyoumeans;¬
         } else if(!_.isUndefined(result.queryresult.didyoumeans)) {¬
             if (!_.isArray(result.queryresult.didyoumeans)){¬
                 result.queryresult.didyoumeans = [result.queryresult.didyoumeans];¬
             }¬
             $scope.getResults({input: result.queryresult.didyoumeans[0].val, didyoumeans:    result.queryresul    t.didyoumeans});¬
             return;¬
         }¬

         $scope.loading = false;¬

         $scope.podRequestStatus.init = true;¬

         if(result.queryresult.success === false) {  //TODO is this result.results.queryresult.success??¬
             if(result.queryresult.error !== false) {¬
                 $log.error('Results error', 'code: ' + result.queryresult.error.code, 'msg: ' + result.quer    yresult.error.msg);¬
                 switch (result.queryresult.error.code){¬
                     case '3000':¬
                         $location.url('/blockedip');¬
                         break;¬
                 }¬

                 return;¬
             }¬ 

             if($scope.results.queryresult.examplepage && $scope.results.queryresult.examplepage.category) {    ¬
                 $scope.examples();¬
             }¬
             // convert tips to an array if we have a single item¬
             if($scope.results.queryresult.tips && !_.isArray($scope.results.queryresult.tips)){¬
                 $scope.results.queryresult.tips = [$scope.results.queryresult.tips];¬
             }¬
             $log.error('Results error');¬
             return;¬
         }¬

         $scope.results.queryresult.pods = _.map($scope.results.queryresult.pods, function(pod) {¬
             pod.priority = PodService.priority.initial;¬
             return pod;¬
         });¬

         if ($scope.results.queryresult.sources && _.where($scope.results.queryresult.sources, {'text':'Fina    ncial data'})) {¬
             $scope.$emit('financialData', true);¬
         } else {¬
             $scope.$emit('financialData', false);¬
         }¬ ¬

         $scope.asyncPods(PodService.priority.async, 'async');¬
         $scope.recalculate();¬
         $scope.related();¬

     }).error(function() {¬
         $log.error('error occurred during ResultsService.get call in ResultsController');¬                 
     });¬
 };¬
```

The functions asyncPods, recalculate and related are three other methods within the ResultsController.

Edited:  Having fixed the first error, I now get the following error when running the tests:

```
Chrome 35.0 (Mac) Controller: ResultsController Should simulate requesting results from the api FAILED
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Scope.$scope.getResults (/Users/maryc/wa/.tmp_test/results-controller.js:222:36)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/maryc/wa/app/results/results-controller_test.js:67:16)
```

This error comes from the line at the beginning of getResults() which calls ResultsService.get().  This seems to imply that my promise is either not being resolved, or the call $scope.getResults() is somehow failing?

The code for the .get() function of ResultsService is:

```
      get: function(query) {¬
          this.reset();¬
          return ApiService.get({¬
              params: UtilService.merge(query, {¬
                  async: true,¬
                  scantimeout: 1,¬
                  formattimeout: 8,¬
                  parsetimeout: 5,¬
                  format: 'image,plaintext,imagemap',¬
                  banners: 'true'¬
              }),¬
              timeout: abort.promise,¬
              type: 'init',¬
              cache: UserService.user.cacheResults¬
          }).success(function(data){results.queryresult = data.queryresult;});¬                              
      },¬
```

I'm wondering now if the problem is that .get itself contains a promise?

Comment: Please check if the `ResultsServiceMock.get()` is really get called.

Comment: so it seems like ResultsServiceMock.get() is not actually getting called, but I have no idea why that is the case.

Comment: Could you show the implementation of the `$scope.getResults()` function? We can start from there to figure out the problem.

Comment: Sure, I will edit the question to include the getResults() code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the information you have included so far, this is my guess of what might cause the problem.

In your `$scope.getResults()` method, you call the `get()` method of `ResultsService`, so it seems like a name of the service is `ResultsService`.

But in the unit testing, you pass the `ResultsServiceMock` as `results`:

```
ctrl = $controller('ResultsController', {
  $scope: $scope,
  results: ResultsServiceMock,
  route: RouteServiceMock
});
```

It should be `ResultsService` instead like this:

```
ctrl = $controller('ResultsController', {
  $scope: $scope,
  ResultsService: ResultsServiceMock,
  RouteService: RouteServiceMock
});
```

After this change, you might encounter another problems, but it should take you pass the error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'resolve' of undefined
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You are correct, that did solve my initial problem!  However, it does lead to another error, which I don't understand; I've edited the question to reflect the new error.  If you could in any way look at that one as well, I would be really grateful.

Comment: I think you should start to debug the unit testing in the DevTools. You might see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15906903/debug-in-browser-using-testacular-now-karma) to get started on how to set a breakpoint.

Comment: For the second error, I don't see the `RouteService.getParams()` is called anywhere, please include the code that make a call and the `RouteService.getParams()` itself.

Comment: So I have worked through most of the errors coming up, which ended up being dumb mistakes.  I'm left with the following error:

    Chrome 35.0 (Mac) Controller: ResultsController Should simulate requesting results from the api FAILED
    TypeError: undefined is not a function
     at Scope.$scope.getResults(/Users/maryc/wa/.tmp_test/results-controller.js:222:36)
     at null.<anonymous> (/Users/maryc/wa/app/results/results-controller_test.js:67:16)

which is the line in getResults which calls ResultsService.get which implies my promise is not being resolved or $scope.getResults is failing.

Comment: What is in the results-controller.js on line 222? The error indicate that it come from there.

Comment: See the end of the post now; I've simplified things down and put in the real error.  Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: The promise from `$q.defer`, that you used as a mock, doesn't have the `.success()` method. The `.success()` method is a special one added by the `$http` service. If you also want it, you could see the implementation of it here: [http.js#L743](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.21/src/ng/http.js#L743)

Comment: Yeah, I had just realised that fact, about the q not having a .success method.  However when I'm not looking at mocking $http, they all involve making actual ajax call.  Internally, obviously, .get is making a $http request, but I don't want to mock that; I just want to mock the successful return of a promise.  Is it possible to do that simply with $httpbackend?